# Why doesn't JS call a function on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
function mobileNavTop () {
  if($('#mobile-navigation').offset().top <= 25) {
    $('#mobile-navigation').css({'position':'absolute', 'right':'0', 'top':'18px'});
    $('.jq1').css({'position':'absolute'});
    $('.move_up').hide();
  } else {
    $('#mobile-navigation').removeAttr('style');
    $('.jq1').removeAttr('style');
    $('.move_up').removeAttr('style');
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  move_up = $('.move_up');

  $('.move_up').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
  });

  if ($('#mobile-navigation').offset().top <= 25) { move_up.hide(); }

  mobileNavTop();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  mobileNavTop();
});
```

The idea is that when I have the navigation scrolled lower than 25px from the top, a bit of `css` happens. And this works on `document.ready`, but not on `scroll` (it doesn't `removeAttr('style')` for whatever the reason. What could cause this?

**Edit**

It works if I scroll up (load the page when `offset().top > 25`), but not if I scroll it down.

Comment: Just make sure the $(window).scroll is inside document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll event must also be inside the `document.ready` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).scroll(function(){
     mobileNavTop();
  });
});
```

> Some recommendations:

You've missed `var` for   `move_up = $('.move_up');`, this will make `move_up` to be global variable and also when you refer to `jquery` wrapped object. its good to use `$move_up`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $move_up = $('.move_up');

  $move_up.click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
  });

  if ($('#mobile-navigation').offset().top <= 25) { $move_up.hide(); }

   $(window).scroll(function(){
     mobileNavTop();
  }).trigger("scroll");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your `scroll` function inside `$(function(){` tag.
try below one:

```
$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).height()==$(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()){
        alert('I am at bottom');
        //mobileNavTop();
});
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/xGV8Q/28/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop().valueOf() > 25) { 
        //code
    }
    else{
        //code
    }
});
});
 </script>
```